# Rust - Hexadecimal to Base64 conversion (Cryptopals challenge 1)

Tags: rust, base64

Here's my solution to the first challenge of the Cryptopals Crypto Challanges (https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/1).

I decided to use a cargo workspace to structure my project with the library crates inside the `crates/` directory and the binary crates (the solutions to the challenges) inside the `challenges/` directory, so, if it is not too subjective, i would also like to know if the project structure makes sense.

## Challenge

> #### Convert hex to base64
>
> The string:
>
> ```
> 49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d
> ```
>
> Should produce:
>
> ```
> SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t
> ```
>
> So go ahead and make that happen. You'll need to use this code for the
> rest of the exercises.
>
> #### Cryptopals Rule
>
> Always operate on raw bytes, never on encoded strings. Only use hex
> and base64 for pretty-printing.

## Workspace Structure

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── challenges
│   └── set1
│       └── challenge-1
│           ├── Cargo.toml
│           └── src
│               └── main.rs
├── crates
│   └── encoding
│       ├── Cargo.toml
│       └── src
│           ├── error.rs
│           └── lib.rs
└── README.md
```

## The code

- **challenges/set-1/challenge-1/src/main.rs**

```
use encoding::{Encode, Decode};

static HEX_INPUT: &'static str = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
static EXPECTED_B64_OUTPUT: &'static str = "SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t";

fn main() {
    let decoded_input = Vec::from_hex(HEX_INPUT).unwrap();
    let b64_out = decoded_input.to_base64();
    
    println!("Hexadecimal input: {}", HEX_INPUT);
    println!("Base64 output: {}", b64_out);

    assert_eq!(b64_out, EXPECTED_B64_OUTPUT);
}
```

- **crates/encoding/src/lib.rs**

````
mod error;
pub use crate::error::*;

/// Types that can hold the result of hexadecimal and base64 decoding
pub trait Decode: Sized {
    /// Converts the given hexadecimal string to an instance of type `Self`.
    ///
    /// Both lower-case an upper-case letters are supported.
    ///
    /// # Examples
    ///
    /// ```
    /// use encoding::Decode;
    ///
    /// let result = Vec::from_hex("1a3d44").unwrap();
    /// assert_eq!(result, vec![26, 61, 68]);
    /// ```
    fn from_hex(s: &str) -> Result<Self, DecodeHexError>;
}

impl Decode for Vec<u8> {
    fn from_hex(s: &str) -> Result<Self, DecodeHexError> {
        if s.len() % 2 != 0 {
            return Err(DecodeHexError::OddLength);
        }

        let mut bytes = Vec::with_capacity(s.len() / 2);

        for i in (0..s.len()).step_by(2) {
            match u8::from_str_radix(&s[i..i + 2], 16) {
                Ok(b) => bytes.push(b),
                _ => {
                    return Err(DecodeHexError::InvalidHexChar);
                }
            }
        }

        Ok(bytes)
    }
}

/// Types that can be encoded to hexadecimal and base64
pub trait Encode {
    /// Encodes the given type into a base64 string
    ///
    /// # Examples
    ///
    /// ```
    /// use crate::encoding::Encode;
    ///
    /// let input = vec![108, 105, 103, 104, 116, 32, 119, 111, 114, 107];
    /// let result = input.to_base64();
    /// assert_eq!(result, String::from("bGlnaHQgd29yaw=="));
    /// ```
    fn to_base64(&self) -> String;
}

impl Encode for Vec<u8> {
    fn to_base64(&self) -> String {
        let mut base64 = String::with_capacity(4 * self.len() / 3);

        for block in self.chunks(3) {
            for b64_char in block_to_base64(block) {
                base64.push(b64_char);
            }
        }

        // padding
        if self.len() % 3 >= 1 {
            base64.pop();
            if self.len() % 3 == 1 {
                base64.pop();
                base64.push('=');
            }
            base64.push('=');
        }

        base64
    }
}

/// Converts a block of 3 bytes to an iterator with 4 base64 encoded characters
fn block_to_base64(block: &[u8]) -> Vec<char> {
    let mut b64_chars = Vec::with_capacity(4);

    let (a, b, c) = match block.len() {
        3 => (block[0], block[1], block[2]),
        2 => (block[0], block[1], 0),
        1 => (block[0], 0, 0),
        _ => return vec![],
    };

    // first 6 bits of a
    b64_chars.push(u8_to_base64(a >> 2));

    // last 2 bits of a followed by the first 4 bits of b
    b64_chars.push(u8_to_base64(a % 4 * 16 + (b >> 4)));

    // last 4 bits of b followed by the first 2 bits of c
    b64_chars.push(u8_to_base64(b % 16 * 4 + (c >> 6)));

    // last 6 bits of c
    b64_chars.push(u8_to_base64(c & 0x3f));

    b64_chars
}

/// Converts a u8 representing a base64 sextet to the respective base64 representation
fn u8_to_base64(u: u8) -> char {
    match u {
        0..=25 => (b'A' + u) as char,
        26..=51 => (b'a' + (u - 26)) as char,
        52..=61 => (b'0' + (u - 52)) as char,
        62 => '=',
        63 => '/',
        _ => panic!("byte exceeded range for base64 conversion: {}", u),
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn bytes_from_hex_correct_input() {
        let result = Vec::from_hex("1a3d44").unwrap();
        let expected = vec![26, 61, 68];
        assert_eq!(result, expected);
    }

    #[test]
    fn bytes_from_hex_odd_length() {
        let result = Vec::from_hex("a4b5h");
        let expected = Err(DecodeHexError::OddLength);
        assert_eq!(result, expected);
    }

    #[test]
    fn bytes_from_hex_invalid_byte() {
        let result = Vec::from_hex("bb7do7");
        let expected = Err(DecodeHexError::InvalidHexChar);
        assert_eq!(result, expected);
    }

    #[test]
    fn bytes_from_hex_empty() {
        let result = Vec::from_hex("").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(result, vec![])
    }

    #[test]
    fn bytes_to_base64_padding_0() {
        let input = vec![108, 105, 103, 104, 116, 32, 119, 111, 114];
        let result = input.to_base64();
        let expected = String::from("bGlnaHQgd29y");
        assert_eq!(result, expected);
    }

    #[test]
    fn bytes_to_base64_padding_1() {
        let input = vec![108, 105, 103, 104, 116, 32, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46];
        let result = input.to_base64();
        let expected = String::from("bGlnaHQgd29yay4=");
        assert_eq!(result, expected);
    }

    #[test]
    fn bytes_to_base64_padding_2() {
        let input = vec![108, 105, 103, 104, 116, 32, 119, 111, 114, 107];
        let result = input.to_base64();
        let expected = String::from("bGlnaHQgd29yaw==");
        assert_eq!(result, expected);
    }

    #[test]
    fn bytes_to_base64_empty() {
        let input = vec![];
        let result = input.to_base64();
        let expected = String::from("");
        assert_eq!(result, expected);
    }
}
````

- **crates/encoding/src/error.rs**

```
use std::fmt;

/// Errors that can occur while decoding hexadecimal strings
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum DecodeHexError {
    /// An hexadecimal string must have an even length
    OddLength,

    /// Attempt to parse a char that does not represent an hexadecimal value
    InvalidHexChar,
}

impl std::error::Error for DecodeHexError {}

impl fmt::Display for DecodeHexError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            DecodeHexError::OddLength => "input string has an odd number of bytes".fmt(f),
            DecodeHexError::InvalidHexChar => {
                "input string contains atleast one invalid character".fmt(f)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Naming

In Rust, a crate is just a unit of "packaging", so the `crates` directory carries little meaning.

If you want to separate the helper libraries in there, it may be better name it `libraries`, `libs`, `utils`, ...

You may also consider doing without for now. A binary can have sub-modules, and unless you end up actually reusing libraries, you're just adding overhead for nothing.

#### Typing

You use `&str` for hexadecimal and `String` for base64, which is fairly arbitrary. It would be better, instead, to create new types.

```rust
/// Hexadecimal encoded value.
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Hex(String);

/// Base64 encoded value.
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Base64(String);
```

This way, there's no ambiguity as to which encoding is used, and the constructor can assert that only adequate values are passed in:

```rust
impl TryFrom<String> for Hex {
    type Error = DecodeHexError;

    fn try_from(s: String) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if s.len() % 2 != 0 {
            return Err(DecodeHexError::OddLength);
        }

        if s.as_bytes().any(|b| !b.is_ascii_hexdigit()) {
            return Err(DecodeHexError::InvalidHexChar);
        }

        Ok(Self(s))
    }
}

//  Similar implementation for `Base64`.
```

#### New traits are for new meanings

There's no need to define new traits to convert from one type to another, really.

Rust already provides generic conversion traits (`From` and `TryFrom`), which should you reuse for maximum compatibility with the rest of the ecosystem.

In this case, since the conversions are infallible, `From` is the appropriate one:

```rust
impl<'a> From<&'a Hex> for Vec<u8> { ... }

impl<'a> From<&'a [u8]> for Base64 { ... }
```

*Note: the validation step was moved to the constructor, so there's no need to revalidate now, which is why the conversions can no longer fail.*

#### No indexes!

Rust has a *very* powerful suite of iterators, so that indexes are typically unnecessary.

Not using indexes means:

1. No messing up indexes.
2. No bounds-checking.
3. More expressive logic.

For example, the decode step can be rewritten as:

```rust
impl<'a> From<&'a Hex> for Vec<u8> {
    fn from(h: &'a Hex) -> Self {
        fn decode_hexdigit(digit: u8) -> u8 {
            if digit.is_ascii_digit() {
                digit - b'0'
            } else {
                digit.to_ascii_uppercase() - b'A' + 10
            }
        }

        let mut bytes = Vec::with_capacity(h.len() / 2);

        //  For stable Rust, use `chunks_exact(2)` instead.
        for [high, low] in h.as_bytes().array_chunks::<2>() {
            let high = decode_hexdigit(high) << 4;
            let low = decode_hexdigit(low);

            bytes.push(high + low)
        }

        bytes
    }
}
```

The loop can also be rewritten in a function way:

```rust
h.as_bytes()
    .array_chunks::<2>()
    .map(|[high, low]| {
        let high = decode_hexdigit(high) << 4;
        let low = decode_hexdigit(low);

        high + low
    })
    .collect()
```

#### Avoid extraneous allocations

Your `block_to_base64` function does not, as it claims, returns an iterator. Instead it returns a `Vec`, which will perform a temporary allocation which you will immediately throw away.

You can either change the function to accept the buffer to push into as a mutable argument -- no shame in that -- or actually return a result which doesn't allocate for nothing.

Note that since you actually never invoke the function with an empty slice, you could easily just return an array `[char; 4]`, although for performance I'd advise returning a `[u8; 4]`, and transform each into `char` at the last moment (4 bytes should be returned in a register, 16 bytes may not).

I also chose to replace the `match` to avoid having an "invalid" case on the hands, but that's fairly personal.

The code is very similar to your own, really:

```rust
fn block_to_base64(block: &[u8]) -> [u8; 4] {
    debug_assert!(!block.is_empty());
    debug_assert!(block.len() < 4);

    let a = block.get(0).unwrap_or(0);
    let b = block.get(1).unwrap_or(0);
    let c = block.get(2).unwrap_or(0);

    let mut result = [0; 4];

    //  First 6 bits of `a`.
    result[0] = u8_to_base64(a >> 2);

    ...

    result
}
```

And with that we can write the encoding step:

```rust
impl<'a> From<&'a [u8]> for Base64 {
    fn from(bytes: &'a [u8]) -> Self {
        let mut result = String::with_capacity(4 * self.len() / 3);

        for block in bytes.chunks(3) {
            for c in block_to_base64(block) {
                result.push(c as char);
            }
        }

        match bytes.len() % 3 {
            0 => (),
            1 => {
                result.pop();
                result.pop();
                result.push('=');
                result.push('=');
            }
            2 => {
                result.pop();
                result.push('=');
            }
        }

        Self(result)
    }
}
```

#### Putting altogether

The challenge can then be rewritten as:

```rust
use std::error::Error;

use encoding::{Hex, Base64};

static HEX_INPUT: &'static str = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
static EXPECTED_B64_OUTPUT: &'static str = "SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t";

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let input: Hex = String::from(HEX_INPUT).try_into()?;
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = input.into();
    let output: Base64 = bytes.into();

    println!("Hexadecimal input: {}", HEX_INPUT);
    println!("Base64 output: {}", output.as_str());

    assert_eq!(output.as_str(), EXPECTED_B64_OUTPUT);
}
```

*Note: you'll need to implement `as_str`, and may consider implementing `Deref<str>` and `Display`, for both `Hex` and `Base64`. It's easy, just delegate to the wrapped `String`.*